# Java- Builiding a recursion that replace even digits with zero

Tags: java, recursion

Hello i need to build a recursion that replace the  even digits with zero:
for exmaple - the number 1254  will be 1050
the number 332- will be 330
and the number 24 - will be 0

i started working on it but got pretty clueless after a while

```
 public static int replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(int number){
    if(number<1)
        return number;
    if(number%2==0 && number%10!=0){
        int temp=number%10;
        return(number/10+replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(number-temp));
    }
    return(replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(number/10));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 1254;
        System.out.println(num1 + " --> " + replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(num1));

        int num2 = 332;
        System.out.println(num2 + " --> " + replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(num2));

        int num3 = 24;
        System.out.println(num3 + " --> " + replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(num3));

        int num4 = 13;
        System.out.println(num4 + " --> " + replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(num4));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clueless"? Do you get wrong results? Do you get any error message? How can we help you if you didn't say what your problem is???

Comment: do you really need recursion or even a simple iteration will be good?

Answer (score 4):

Since your method only looks at the last digit, it should always call itself with `input / 10` when `input >= 10`.

You then take the value returned by the recursion, multiply it by 10 and add the last digit back, if odd.

```
public static int replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(int number) {
    int result = 0;
    if (number >= 10)
        result = replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(number / 10) * 10;
    if (number % 2 != 0)
        result += number % 10;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you need a 1-liner, here it goes: ;)

```
public static int replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(int number) {
    return (number%2 == 0 ? 0 : number % 10) + (number<10 ? 0 : 10 * replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(number / 10));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well ... designing a recursive algorithm has always the same steps:

1. Identify the *base case*, that is the scenario that will terminate the recursive calls.
2. Reduce the *problem* to being smaller (towards the base case).

For this requirement the problem can easily be made smaller by dividing by 10. That also easily leads to the base case: A single digit is the base case. So a quick implementation can be:

```
public static int replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(int number) {
    // I added handling of negative numbers ...
    if (number < 0) {
        return -replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(-number);
    }

    // base case
    if (number < 10) {
        return replaceOneDigit(number);
    }

    // recursion
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int remainder = number / 10;
    return replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(remainder) * 10 + replaceOneDigit(lastDigit);
}

public static int replaceOneDigit(int digit) {
    return (digit % 2 == 0) ? 0 : digit;
}
```

I added a helper method for converting even digits to zero.

The output now is:

> 1254 --> 1050
>
> 332 --> 330
>
> 24 --> 0
>
> 13 --> 13

Answer (score 0):

You need to take track of the current position in your number.
In your current function, you will return only the first digit of your number (because you divide it by 10 everytime the recursion is called).

```
public static int replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(int number, int position){

    // cancel condition:
    if(number < 10 * position) {
        return number;
    }

    // edit number:
    if (position > 0) {
        int currentNumber = number / (10 * position);    
    } else {
        currentNumber = number;
    }

    if(currentNumber%2==0){  //even?
        int multiplyValue = currentNumber % 10; // get rest of division by 10 (== digit in current position)
        number = number - (multiplyValue * (10 * position)); // set current position to zero
    }

    // recursive call:
    return replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(number,position+1);
}
```

Didn't test my code, but I hope you get an idea of how to do it.
Use `replaceEvenDigitsWithZero(num1,0)` to start.

Answer (score -2):

1 convert to String

2 F(string): take the **first** number: replace 2,4,6,8 characters by 0

3 concatenate to F(the remaining string)

4 convert to int

Comment: where's the recursion ?

Comment: Where is the recursion in this algorithm?

Comment: @BigMike   + recursion !